# Why did I get the Copy Editor badge one edit early?

Tags: support, edit-badges

My profile displays 499 posts edited, but still the newest badge is Copy Editor, which requires 500 edits.

How is this possible?
[image]

Comment: might be caching?

Comment: I don't think so, Its like that for couple of days now. I stopped editing to be sure that It is not because of caching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A possible scenario is this:

- You perform your 500-th edit on some post.
- The badge is awarded.
- Some post you edited is deleted and the edit does not count anymore.
- Your badge does not get revoked, because badges are only revoked in exceptional circumstances.

To confirm this, you would need the privilege to see deleted posts (10 k) on the relevant site.

Comment: would the badge not be revoked in that case?

Comment: @Mohit: Except in extraordinary circumstances, badges aren't revoked.

Comment: @MohitKanwar: Badges are only revoked in exceptional cases, e.g., if you have actively gamed the system to obtain it. For example, I still have my [Good answer badge](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer?userid=16889) on Skeptics though the corresponding answer was deleted.

Comment: okay! That's nice :)